# Add bottom margin to elements in jQuery Masonry

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

I'm using a forked version of David Desandro's jQuery Masonry plug-in which allows me to set a width for the Columns.

> spacerWidth: 10,

http://github.com/gilmoreorless/masonry

But how can you set a bottom margin on the element to give it equal spacing to it's column?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can give a CSS margin-bottom to each of the bricks.